# .Net Core 2.0 MySQL The network path was not found

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net-core

I am creating a new .NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages Web application with Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.5.0. The template already contains the user authentication code, and I want to test my database connection with the user login function. When I try to log in, I get the error message

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> Win32Exception: The network path was not found Unknown location
>
> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

My Windows workstation has a local Microsoft SQL Server and a MySQL server.
I want to connect to the **MySQL** server:

- Host: MY_HOST
- Socket: MySQL
- Port: 3306
- Version: 5.7.18-log MySQL Community Server

My connection string is

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost:3306;Database=MY_DATABASE;Uid=MY_USER;Pwd=MY_PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=True"
```

I have installed the MySql.Data NuGet package in the web application.

- Please correct my connection string and let me know if I need to
  configure the application to use a MySQL database.
- How can I tell .NET that I want to use a MySQL database server?
- How can I specify the port of the local database server? If I add Port=3306 to the connection string I get the error message

> ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'port'.

Comment: Are you missing this ? "Data Source=MSSQL\EXPRESS; Initial Catalog=DBName"

Comment: You write that "Trusted_Connection=True". Could you remove that statement and can you try again later?

Comment: And you can specify your port number such as; Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;

Comment: @Zwei James I need to connect to the MySQL server. What is the correct Data Source?

Comment: @MetehanSenol When I add the Port=option I get "ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'port'."

Comment: @MetehanSenol Removing "Trusted_Connection=True" does not help.

Comment: Please check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192184/logic-behind-data-source-local-in-connection-string

Comment: @LaszloPinter the error message you get is a Microsoft SQL Server connection timeout error not mysql error type. I think there is another sql server connection string that you have forgotten in a different place. Please check your another config and database objects.